# Entity & Linq not filtering properly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have 3 table's

1. BaseNews
2. EN_NewsDetails(foreign key from BaseNews table)
3. HI_NewsDetails(foreign key from BaseNews table)

In my code when i select any language it needs to retrieve that language details only.BUT in here it returns all the EN & HI language details also.

> In here when i select my language as EN but i received a return Both EN & HI language details

### Code

```
public List<BaseNews> GetAllNewsDetailsByLang(string lang)
{
    List<BaseNews> prd = new List<BaseNews>();

    if (lang.Trim() == "EN")
    {
        prd = (from c in context.BaseNews
                join x in context.EN_NewsDetails
                on c.Nid equals x.enId
                where c.IsActive == true
                select c).ToList();
    }
    else if (lang.Trim() == "HI")
    {
        prd = (from k in context.BaseNews
                join x in context.HI_NewsDetails
                on k.Nid equals x.enId
                where k.IsActive == true
                select k).ToList();
    }

    return prd;
}
```

### Definitions

```
public partial class BaseNews
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public BaseNews()
    {
        this.EN_NewsDetails = new HashSet<EN_NewsDetails>();
        this.HI_NewsDetails = new HashSet<HI_NewsDetails>();
    }

    public int Nid { get; set; }
    public int Category_CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string ThumbImagePath { get; set; }
    public string OriginalImagePath { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
}

public partial class EN_NewsDetails
{
    public int NDetailsId { get; set; }
    public int enId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }

    public virtual BaseNews BaseNews { get; set; }
}

public partial class HI_NewsDetails
{
    public int NDetailsId { get; set; }
    public int enId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }

    public virtual BaseNews BaseNews { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As I see what this code does: if you pass "EN" it returns all `BaseNews` that have any `EN_NewsDetails` entries. If you pass "HI" it returns all `BaseNews` that have any `HI_NewsDetails` entries. I don't see where it includes those details. And even if did include them - it's pefectly possible that both EN and HI are present.

Comment: Could you please post also the definitions of `BaseNews`, `EN_NewsDetails` and `HI_NewsDetails`? Thanks

Comment: @Christos you ask about entity framework .tt files ?

Comment: @TechGuy Nope, I am asking about the defintion of these classes. If you right click on their names there should be a link go to definition.

Comment: @Christos OP updated.Please check

Comment: @TechGuy Could you please post also the defintions of `EN_NewsDetails ` and `HI_NewsDetails`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are returning list of `BaseNews` but saying that "it needs to retrieve that language details only".

Comment: @Christos OP updated with EN_NewsDetails and HI_NewsDetails

Comment: @Evk Yes.Because BaseNews table doen't have a Language specific details.All the language specific details are in seperate language table's like EN_NewsDetails

Comment: So how do you get those details? You return BaseNews, not details.

Comment: @Evk I need both BaseNews and the selected language tables details also.

Comment: @TechGuy Please check my update and let me know. Thanks

Comment: I think that you need to turn lazy loading off

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
public List<BaseNews> GetAllNewsDetailsByLang(string lang)
{
    var newsDetails = new List<BaseNews>();

    if (lang.Trim() == "EN")
    {
        newsDetails = context.EN_NewsDetails
                             .Include(en_nd=>en_nd.BaseNews)
                             .Where(en_nd=>en_nd.BaseNews.IsActive.HasValue 
                                        && en_nd.BaseNews.IsActive)
                             .Select(en_nd=>en_nd.BaseNews)
                             .ToList();
    else if (lang.Trim() == "HI")
    {
        newsDetails = context.HI_NewsDetails
                             .Include(hi_nd=>hi_nd.BaseNews)
                             .Where(hi_nd=>hi_nd.BaseNews.IsActive.HasValue  
                                        && hi_nd.BaseNews.IsActive)
                             .Select(hi_nd=>hi_nd.BaseNews)
                             .ToList();
    }

    return newsDetails;
}
```

**Notes**

Despite the fact that the above code might fix your filtering issue, I see a few points that you should make more clear.

- If the Language is neither "EN" nor "HI", you want to return just an empty list. Is that correct? Actually the code does exactly this in this case and I am not sure if you want this.
- You are talking about about language details, while you return BaseNews objects. I don't think this is consistent, at least in a conceptual level.

Regarding the second bullet, try to read the above method and you will get what I mean. It's name is `GetAllNewDetailsByLang`. That's ok. Step over the first lines of the method, we return a list of `BaseNews` objects. There is a misnaming created by me, in order to *fix* this issue. But regardless the method's purpose or the rest code or whatever, the following line:

```
var newsDetails = new List<BaseNews>();
```

is not clear. The reason it's isn't is the fact that you are not clear about what you want to return. Making this clear, we could change the namigs and fix both the above bullets.

Answer (score 0):

We don't see what you are doing with the results above, but I also see that the context isn't disposed.  Thus, if you access that navigation property off of BaseNews and lazy loading is turned on (it is by default), EF will automatically go fetch that data for you.  You can turn off lazy loading for the specific context by doing

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```